# How to generate an expiring URL for content on AWS S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I would like to create a temporary URL for users to download content from my aws s3 bucket. Is there a tutorial on how this can be done quickly and easily? I am using php for my server side code

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is built into S3 and its PHP SDK.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#creating-a-pre-signed-url

```
// Get a pre-signed URL for an Amazon S3 object
// $client is an instance of AWS SDK's S3Client
$signedUrl = $client->getObjectUrl('my-bucket', 'filename.ext', '+10 minutes');
// > https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.ext?AWSAccessKeyId=[...]&Expires=[...]&Signature=[...]
```

Comment: Version 3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html

Answer (score -1):

One way that this can be done is to encrypt the current date and time using a symmetric encryption function, such as mcrypt_encrypt.  Then, the encrypted text is appended to the URL as the query string.

Then, when the URL is accessed, the URL's target script decrypts the query string, to get the date and time that the link was created, and compares this to the current date and time.  If more than the allowed interval of time has passed, then the link is deemed to be invalid.

This is the script to create the expiring link:

```
        <?
        define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', '9ab6c9abcd827e8726f92275f87e7abc820937d87e871c85e982d8eb08ba87ef');  // this is super-secret.  don't let it get out!
        $expiration=300;  //link expires in 300 seconds

        $expirationtime=time()+$expiration;
        //print $expirationtime;
        $URL="http://hostname.domain.tld/path/to/validationscript.php?" . urlencode(mc_encrypt($expirationtime, ENCRYPTION_KEY));
        print "Link is: <BR>" . $URL . "<BR><BR>Please note that this link is valid only for " . $expiration . " seconds.";


        // Encrypt Function
        function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key){
            $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
            $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
            $key = pack('H*', $key);
            $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
            $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
            $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
            return $encoded;
        }
        ?>
```

The link that the above script will produce will look something like this, where the expiration is encrypted and stuffed in the query string.

```
http://hostname.domain.tld/path/to/validationscript.php?FsUBxPBe88SFu1wlJav8Wk23nnyGfdi%2FP4p95lK7DuErfjGDhUB8%2B1G02WeDqfb8krFjo5ABNRlcTwTs7eNDAzh2ixPsBFUqZWYaRyOQHDaEiuHA0SLpZVQH8SAnnGiQ%7C3LmPuTeozYqr3HhMIGC%2FoBM2Kd6qfb81LYgPZjmgpC8%3D
```

The expiring link points to the validation script below, which checks whether or not the link is still valid:

```
            <?
            define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', '9ab6c9abcd827e8726f92275f87e7abc820937d87e871c85e982d8eb08ba87ef');  // this is super-secret.  don't let it get out!

            $expirationtime=mc_decrypt(urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), ENCRYPTION_KEY);
            if(time()<$expirationtime) {
                print "link is still valid.<BR>";
            } else {
                print "link is no longer valid.<BR>";
            }


            // Decrypt Function
            function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key){
                $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt);
                $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
                $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
                $key = pack('H*', $key);        
                $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
                $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
                $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
                $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
                if($calcmac!==$mac){ return false; }
                $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
                return $decrypted;
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Sure.  I edited my answer to provide a working example.

Comment: Why do this when the S3 SDK natively supports an expiring link in only a few lines of code?